# Get id from previous processor NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

[Processors I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOavv.png)

Is it possible that the processor "InvokeHTTP" takes the information "id" from the previous processor(in this case SELECT_FROM_SNOWFLAKE)?

[Where i want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWI2R.png)

I would like the "Remote URL" to be something like:

```
http://${hostname()}:8080/nifi-api/processors/${previousProcessorId()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. But you can get name, id or other properties for current processor group using ExecuteScript or ExecuteGroovy processors somewhere in this flow to find these informations  with script:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return 
processGroupId = context.procNode?.processGroupIdentifier ?: 'unknown'
processGroupName = context.procNode?.getProcessGroup().getName() ?: 'unknown'
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'processGroupId', processGroupId)
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'processGroupName', processGroupName)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

After that, you can find get the id of this snow_flake processor in this processor group for example in rest api.

Answer (score 0):

the `Remote URL` property in `InvokeHTTP` processor supports nifi expression language.

So, if previous processor sets attribute `hostname` then you can use it as `http://${hostname}:8080/...`

However SelectSQL returns result in Avro format.

Probably before InvokeHTTP you need to convert avro to json and then evaluatejsonpath to extract required values into attributes.